# how to fix Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Posts\PostsController::show() must be an instance of App\Post, string given

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in laravel. Can you help me? I don't understand where is the problem:

> Argument 2 passed to
>   App\Http\Controllers\Posts\PostsController::show() must be an instance
>   of App\Post, string given

PostController

```
public function show( Category $category  , Post $post )
{

        return view('posts.post',[

            'post' => $post,

        ]);

}
```

Model Post.php

```
class Post extends Model
{


    protected $fillable = ['user_id','category_id','name','slug','body'];
    protected $with = ['user','category'];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        self::creating(function($model){
            $model->slug = str::slug($model->name);
        });
    }

    public function path()
    {
        return "/blog/{$this->category->slug}/{$this->id}";
    }

    public function user ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

    }//

    public function category ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(category::class);

    }
}
```

Web.php

```
route::group(['namespace'=>'Posts','prefix' => 'blog'], function (){

    route::get('','PostsController@index')->name('blog');
    route::get('{Category}','PostsController@index');
    route::get('{Category}/{post}','PostsController@show')->name('post');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your parameters in the route. change `Category` to `category`

```
Route::get('{category}/{post}','PostsController@show')->name('post');
```

Or make make the both parameter starts with a capital letter.

```
Route::get('{Category}/{Post}','PostsController@show')->name('post');
```

Or the first one starts with small letter

```
Route::get('{category}/{Post}','PostsController@show')->name('post');
```

Answer (score 0):

`public function show( Category $category  , Post $post )`

Above line tells that the first parameter which `show` function receives will be an instance of `Category` and second parameter will be an instance of `Post`

so you need to be careful that when you use the route:

```
route::get('{Category}/{post}','PostsController@show')->name('post');
```

always satisfy those conditions.

If you are not sure then just remove the type casting so thatparameters can be of `any` type like so:

```
public function show ($category, $post)
```